# Login page using java spring at back end and AngularJS at front end.

Tags: java, angularjs

i am facing problem in making Login page using Spring and Angular java script. Please suggest me how to make this. i am using Angular java script as front end and java in back end.
i see lots of stuff but it didn't help me out.i know i am asking too much but i have only last hope.

Comment: What is your exact query? Be specific

Comment: Login page with angularjs and java.

Comment: If you want to implement spring security  then you have to decide first which authentication method you want to use /have for example LDAP Authentication .. 

I would recommend to go through this tutorial first :

https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide first whether you want to implement spring security ? and if yes then you have to decide  which authentication method you want to use /have in your application  for example LDAP Authentication ..

I would recommend to go through this tutorial first :

https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii

and

https://dzone.com/articles/login-page-angular-js-and